# To check whether the numbers are coprime or not

Tags: python-3.8

To check whether the numbers are coprime or not.
I've actually used an easier logic here which makes complete sense, but for some reason, I'm not able to get the correct answer using this code. Please do check the code out and let me know what you think about it :)

```
m = int(input())
n = int(input())
setm = set()
setn = set()
for i in range(1,m+1):
    if (m%i==0):
        setm.add(i)
for j in range(1,n+1):
    if (n%j==0):
        setn.add(j)
if setm.intersection(setn) == '1':
    print('Coprime')
else:
    print('Not coprime')
```

Comment: Hi   This question would better suit into CODE REVIEW https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
m = int(input())
n = int(input())
setm = set()
setn = set()
for i in range(1,m+1):
    if (m%i==0):
        setm.add(i)
for j in range(1,n+1):
    if (n%j==0):
        setn.add(j)

if setm.intersection(setn) == {1}:
    print('Coprime')
else:
    print('Not coprime')
```

Intersection returns a set.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
if setm.intersection(setn) == '1':
```

does not do the comparison correctly. There are many ways to fix it - for example, you could check the length of the intersection:

```
if len(setm.intersection(setn)) == 1:
```

The idea behind this comparison is that `1` will always be in both set of divisors for mathematical reasons, so if the sets intersect on a single item, it must be `1`.

P.S. Note that your algorithm would incorrectly identify two 1s as coprime; this should be fixed with a few additional checks.